# How to save reorder of rows in TableView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I search already a few days to the answer on the question how can I save the reorder TableView with Swift? So many tutorials on the internet show how to reorder but not how to save with UserDefaults.

This is my code right now. What do I wrong?

Please can you help me to the solution? Thank you very much.

```
import UIKit

class soundboardTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var list = ["January","February","March","April","May","June", "July","August","September","October","November", "December"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        let blockItems = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"soundboard")

        if(blockItems != nil) {
            list = blockItems as! [String]
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return list.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }


    /* Override to support editing the table view.*/
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            list.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.list, forKey:"soundboard")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
        let itemToMove = list[indexPath.row]
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        list.insert(itemToMove, at: indexPath.row)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.list, forKey:"soundboard")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        if(self.isEditing) {

        }
    }


    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }



    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }


}
```

Comment: You want `list.insert(itemToMove, at:to.row)` and you don't need to call `synchronize`

Comment: On your delete, instead of calling `reloadData`, call `tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` and the deletion will animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)` has some errors. You should change it to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {
    let itemToMove = list[indexPath.row]
    list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    list.insert(itemToMove, at: to.row)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.list, forKey:"soundboard")
}
```

Notice that I removed `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`. You should remove it from your other methods as well, since it is kind of a non-sense in this case. I have also changed `list.insert(itemToMove, at: indexPath.row)` to `list.insert(itemToMove, at: to.row)`, because you need to place it to the "destination" index, and not put it back from where you removed it.

The rest of your code seems fine. It should be working once you perform these changes.

Comment: @ErwinOudshoorn Your are welcome! If you have questions about this, feel free to ask